# I need to change the fullcalendar header as each month is selected

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to change the header as each month is selected.  This includes text from a database so we are talking about ajax, which I am familiar with.  I just need to know the event that is triggered on a month change and also capture the month/year that is being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The `eventAfterAllRender` callback option is your best bet. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/

Here's a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/jk9u53h6/1/

When all the events are finished rendering (which happens anytime the month, day or week is changed) it convert the current date into a string and replace the title text with it.

```
var dateChanged = function(){
    var currentDate = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
    console.log(currentDate);
    $('.fc-toolbar .fc-left h2').text(currentDate.format());
}
var $fc = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    eventAfterAllRender: dateChanged,
});
```

Not super solid, but you should be able to make it fit your needs.